# android drawing overlay on a view in an async task thread

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask, overlay

please excuse the vague question but i'm new to android and java and and all the stuff i've read about this subject only offers xml code samples which is no use for me as i'm doing everything programatically.

so i have an app that draws music notation and then as the music plays, i need to overlay some kind of cursor (rectangular box ok) over the currently playing note, karaoke style.

i create a view like this

```
Globals.mMainView = new MainView(context);
            Globals.mMainView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 60));
            layout.addView(Globals.mMainView);
```

i save the view reference in a global so i can find it later, (yes i know the java police will be coming for me at this point but i can find a more elegant solution later). note that my view lives in a linear layout because i have another, unrelated view next to it.

drawing in the main threads onDraw works just fine to render the music score.

so, when i hit my play button i start one of these

```
class Play1Activity extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
```

and play the audio in doInBackground and periodically call publishProgress with playback position which in turns causes onProgressUpdate to run in the UI thread where i believe its safe to do drawing

now, i would like to draw something on top of the main view (i have a reference Globals.mMainView) without having to redraw the whole view to save CPU and make the animation look nice. in windows i can draw a rectangle with XOR flags which inverts the part of the score i'm interested in, then do the same operation again to undraw it and then draw in the next position.

at this point i'm clueless on android. perhaps someone could suggest the best path for me to follow. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know which part of the main view should be redraw you can call `invalidate (Rect dirty)` or `invalidate (int l, int t, int r, int b)` on the view. In this case the only dirty area will be redrawn.

Comment: that's interesting, so i put  Globals.mMainView.invalidate(40, 40, 200, 200); in onProgressUpdate and it causes a the system to call OnDraw but what now? how does onDraw know where to redraw?

Comment: i tried not doing anything in onDraw when called via progress update but i just get a blank view. i guess i'm not clear what calling invalidate with args does.

Comment: I am not sure how it actually works but i think this way. You call `invalidate(Rect dirty)` and it causes the system to redraw the view. In your `onDraw()` method you just do usual drawing (draw an overlay in your case). That's all. The trick is that `canvas` object passed to `onDraw` method is clipped with the dirty rect. Thas's why only points located within the rect are actually redrawn.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to be true. in my onDraw i added code to draw only the bit of the screen i'm interested in updating, but that's all i get. the original drawing has gone. i'll poke around a bit more, thanks anyhow

Comment: i suspect my problem is i'm using View. i have a feeling i need to use SurfaceView but haven't really figured that out yet. if i simply replace 'public class MainView extends View'  with 'public class MainView extends SurfaceView' nothing works so there is more to it than that.

Comment: I have never used SurfaceView, but as I know you should also create a rendering thread

Comment: SurfaceView looks very complicated and i guess is for double buffer graphics in games. so i'm currently redrawing the whole thing every 100ms which is easy, but i expect uses a lot of cpu. some kind of floating cursor would do the trick too if that is possible?